Why does smbclient not require security mode? (But mount.cifs does)
I have a windows share that I am able to access with smbclient no problem (where I confirmed the share is using SMB3.11). As I understand, there are security mode implications based on SMB version (albeit I can't find anything delineating the compatibility) i.e. I understand that SMB3+ requires ntlmssp - however, the system has FIPS mode enabled which is known to cause issues; I can't disable FIPS and I don't want to go the Kerberos route.
My question is thus: why does smbclient not require any sort of security mode to connect successfully yet mount.cifs does? Also, is there any mount.cifs security mode "less than" ntlmssp that is compatible with vers=3.11?
Interestingly, when I try to mount with vers=3.11 specifically, I get Invalid argument - maybe my version of mount.cifs, 6.2, is too outdated?
Thanks in advance!
